# Heart/Like Button Linked to Individual Items in a List

Tags: html, css, wordpress, list

Trying to add heart/like buttons on each individual link in a list in Wordpress. 
You can see it here : http://theroadmap.co/strategy/. 
I want the likes/fav be linked to the items, and not to the individual post (I have over 20 links in one post, split into 5 sections).

I used shortcodes of several plugins (ZillaLikes) and they always mess up the CSS + are linked to the individual post and not the item themselves.

You can see my HTML code of one of the sections of a post below:

```
<ol class="rectangle-list">

<li class="tooltip" title="What does a startup CEO actually do?"><a href="LINK TO ARTICLE </a></li>
<p>What does a startup CEO actually do?</p>

<li class="tooltip" title="How to find your competitive advantage"><a href="http://blogs.hbr.org/2013/07/be-the-company-customers-cant/">Be the Company Customers Can't Live Without</a></li>
<p>How to find your competitive advantage</p>

</ol>
```

Thanks!
Dan.

Comment: i'm now using a plugin called likebtn - [link]http://theroadmap.co/generation/ - but it brings the loading time of my site to a crawl because each like button loads separately from an external source. Anyone has other alternatives or ways to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something simple like Font-Awesome. It's very easy to add to your site where-ever you want it and control size, colour etc via CSS.

[Font-Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)

For example a solid heart icon would be added like

```
 <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
```

Comment: that's great visually but there's no 'fav' logic behind it that users can 'like' certain elements....